# pgadmin4 deployment not starting in kubernetes deployment - werkzeug websocket transport not available / 503 service unavailable

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pgadmin

I'm trying to deploy and run an instance of pgadmin4 in a kubernetes environment (private cloud, an a shared kubernetes cluster) with readOnlyRootFilesystem + runAsNonRoot constraints, as well as allowPrivilegeEscalation = false. I have configured additional volumes + Mounts, to get around previous permission issues, but after deployment with helm chart, I now get the following errors/warnings in the cluster logs, After a few minutes the pod crashes and restarts:

```
NOTE: Configuring authentication for DESKTOP mode.
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://0.0.0.0:5050 in your browser.
2023-08-24 11:08:16,198: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-08-24 11:08:16,198: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-08-24 11:08:16,198: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.
2023-08-24 11:08:16,198: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.
 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
 * Debug mode: off
```

And when I try to access the instance in my browser I get "503 service temporarily unavailable"

I am relatively new to kubernetes and struggling to get the instance working in a restrictive kubernetes environment. I deploy with helm chart, but kubernetes objects have been adapted with concrete values for better readability here.

I deploy to a dev cluster, and first of all want to run pgadmin with simple internal authentication.

Does anyone know how to address these problems? i really couldn't find much on the topic. Perhaps something to do with a wrong version of werkzeug being used, but no idea how to fix it.

I tried deployment with the official dockerhub image for pgadmin, but couldn't get it to run because of cluster security constraints

Next steps:
Starting from here: [github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker](https://github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker/tree/master)

I adapted the dockerfile a little bit, using a newer pgadmin whl file from here: [pgadmin4-7.5-py3-none-any.whl](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v7.5/pip/) and used the config_distro.py file from the github repo

**My adapted Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9.17-alpine3.18

# create a non-privileged user to use at runtime
RUN addgroup -g 50 -S pgadmin \
 && adduser -D -S -h /pgadmin -s /sbin/nologin -u 1000 -G pgadmin pgadmin \
 && mkdir -p /pgadmin/config /pgadmin/storage \
 && chown -R 1000:50 /pgadmin

# Install postgresql tools for backup/restore
RUN apk add --no-cache libedit postgresql \
 && cp /usr/bin/psql /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dumpall /usr/bin/pg_restore /usr/local/bin/ \
 && apk del postgresql

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev libffi-dev

ENV PGADMIN_VERSION=7.5
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

COPY pgadmin4-7.5-py3-none-any.whl /pgadmin4-7.5-py3-none-any.whl
RUN apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk linux-headers \
 && pip install --upgrade pip \
 && echo "/pgadmin4-7.5-py3-none-any.whl" | pip install --no-cache-dir -r /dev/stdin \
 && apk del alpine-sdk linux-headers

EXPOSE 5050

COPY config_distro.py /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/

USER pgadmin:pgadmin
CMD ["python", "./usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py"]
VOLUME /pgadmin/
```

I built the image and pushed it to a registry so I could use it for deploying to the cluster.
Next I created the required kubernetes objects (sensitive data like URLS have been replaced with placeholders), where probably some configuration is incorrect, or some ENV Variables are not needed.

deployment: I created additional volumes + volumemounts to get around the readonly filesystem and run the container as the user specified in dockerfile: User 1000 / Group: 50

**deployment.yml**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-test
  namespace: onecpq-playground
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgadmin-test
      deployment: pgadmin-test
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        field.cattle.io/workloadMetrics: '[{"path":"/actuator/prometheus","port":8080,"schema":"HTTP"}]'
      labels:
        app: pgadmin-test
        deployment: pgadmin-test
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: pgadmin-test
                topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
              weight: 100
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: mtr-pullsecret
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 5050
        runAsGroup: 5050
        runAsUser: 5050
      containers:
        - image: myregistry.com/pgadmin-test:latest
          name: pgadmin-test
          env:
          - name: SERVER_PORT
            value: "8080"
          - name: TZ
            value: "Europe/Berlin"
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
            value: "pgadmin@example.com"
          - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: pgadmin-test-secret
                key: password
          - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS
            value: 0.0.0.0
          - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT
            value: "5050" 
          - name: PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX
            value: 'True'

          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED
            value: 'False'
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION
            value: 'False'
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_AUTO_DISCOVER_SERVERS
            value: 'False'
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENABLE_PSQL
            value: 'True'
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES 
            value: "['internal']"
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED
            value: 'False'
          - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_MFA_ENABLED
            value: 'False'

          ports:
            - containerPort: 5050
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 64Mi
              cpu: 250m
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 500m
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              # path: /actuator/health/liveness
              path: /misc/ping
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              # path: /actuator/health/readiness
              path: /misc/ping
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1000
            runAsGroup: 50
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cache-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
            - name: storage-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin/storage
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /pgadmin    
            - name: log
              mountPath: /var/log/pgadmin
      volumes:
        - name: cache-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pg-cache-data
        - name: storage-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pg-storage-data
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir:
            medium: "Memory"
        - name: log
          emptyDir:
            medium: "Memory"
```

**Ingress.yml **(needed because postgreSQL db is outside of cluster)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-test-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: pgadmin-test
spec:
  rules:
    - host: pgadmin-test-mynamespace.examplecluster.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: pgadmin-test-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - pgadmin-test-mynamespace.examplecluster.com
```

**pvc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pg-cache-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "nfs-storage"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pg-storage-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "nfs-storage"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

**secret.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-test-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: RzUjb3IqMnNuZk40dkc=
```

**service.yml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-test-service
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: pgadmin-test
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: pgadmin-test
```

I expected to be able to access pgadmin via the ingress URL, but get 503 temporarily unavailable error. and the errors from cluster logs listed above.

I did not include values.yaml and chart.yaml, because all values from there have been hardcoded explicitly into kubernetes object files.

Information about postgreSQL db to connect to has not been included as well, as first of all I want to get the application running, and then connect to DB via web UI